# How to migrate with data update on *one time* joined columns?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, migration

I'm adding a new association to existing models with existing data in a Rails 3.2.x + AR project.

The Migration script:

```
class AddUserToSignups < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    add_column :signups, :user_id, :integer, :default => nil
    add_index :signups, :user_id
    # UPDATE SIGNUPS S JOIN USERS U ON S.EMAIL=U.EMAIL SET S.USER_ID = U.ID
  end
  def down
    drop_column :signups, :user_id
  end
end
```

How do I do a joined update per the comment above with AR?  I come from a Sequel ORM background, so Sequel's approach would be:

```
DB[:signups___s].join(:users___u, :u__id => :s__user_id).update(:s__user_id => :u__id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def up
    add_column :signups, :user_id, :integer, :default => nil
    add_index :signups, :user_id
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("UPDATE SIGNUPS S JOIN USERS U ON S.EMAIL=U.EMAIL SET S.USER_ID = U.ID")
end
```

Comment: Thanks, and this works well, but I'm guessing there's not a Rubyish DSL for A/R that would do this.